Chern character of a cohomology sheaf
I'm having problems with the following computation. I have three locally free sheaves $A$, $B$ and $C$ on a projective surface, and a complex of sheaves $$
0\to A \xrightarrow{\alpha} B \xrightarrow{\beta} C\to 0,
$$
which is exact at $A$ and $C$, but is allowed to have cohomology $K = \ker\beta/\mathrm{Im}\alpha$, which in general is a torsion-free sheaf. Now, I have complete information about the Chern classes of the three locally free sheaves; I need to compute the Chern character of the cohomology $K$.
I figured I'd have a generalization of additivity on exact sequences, and hoped in something in the lines of $\mathrm{ch} K = \mathrm{ch} B - \mathrm{ch} A - \mathrm{ch} C$. However, either I'm very tired or this is wrong.
EDIT: The formula works, a proof is in the comments. Guess I was tired.

Exactness at A and C has no meaning in a 3-term sequence A → B → C.

Thank you @DanAsimov, I really was tired, what I really meant of course was that $\alpha$ is an injective map of sheaves and $\beta$ is surjective. I fixed the question.

@JyrkiLahtonen I guess you're right. My computations were wrong and the formula actually works because of your proof.

It feels weird to promote my comment to an answer, because I have forgotten nearly everything I have ever read/heard about Chern characters. Anyway, apparently they are additive over short exact sequences, and we seem to live in a category, where kernels and cokernels exist. So the general non-sense of splitting the given complex into two short exact sequences:
$$
0\to A\to\mathrm{Ker}(\beta)\to K\to0
$$
and
$$
0\to\mathrm{Ker}(\beta)\to B\to C\to0
$$
will get the job done.
